# Panel data with multiindex

Tags: r, dplyr, plm

I would like to ask how to work with a panel data, or how to tranfort dataset so it can be then modeled as panel data, when it has multiindex?

```
library(tibble)
library(plm)
library(fastDummies)

dataset <- tribble(
  ~country, ~year, ~sex, ~age, ~suicides_no,
  "Albania", 1987, "male", "15-24", 50, 
  "Albania", 1987, "male", "35-50", 20, 
  "Albania", 1987, "male", "50-", 11,
  "Albania", 1987, "female", "15-24", 18, 
  "Albania", 1987, "female", "35-50", 2, 
  "Albania", 1987, "female", "50-", 1,
  "Albania", 1988, "male", "15-24", 50, 
  "Albania", 1988, "male", "35-50", 2, 
  "Albania", 1988, "male", "50-", 11,
  "Albania", 1988, "female", "15-24", 17, 
  "Albania", 1988, "female", "35-50", 20, 
  "Albania", 1988, "female", "50-", 10,
  "Albania", 1989, "male", "15-24", 0, 
  "Albania", 1989, "male", "35-50", 2, 
  "Albania", 1989, "male", "50-", 1,
  "Albania", 1989, "female", "15-24", 7, 
  "Albania", 1989, "female", "35-50", 2, 
  "Albania", 1989, "female", "50-", 1,
  "Germany", 1987, "male", "15-24", 50, 
  "Germany", 1987, "male", "35-50", 2, 
  "Germany", 1987, "male", "50-", 11,
  "Germany", 1987, "female", "15-24", 18, 
  "Germany", 1987, "female", "35-50", 20, 
  "Germany", 1987, "female", "50-", 1,
  "Germany", 1988, "male", "15-24", 0, 
  "Germany", 1988, "male", "35-50", 2, 
  "Germany", 1988, "male", "50-", 110,
  "Germany", 1988, "female", "15-24", 17, 
  "Germany", 1988, "female", "35-50", 20, 
  "Germany", 1988, "female", "50-", 10,
  "Germany", 1989, "male", "15-24", 0, 
  "Germany", 1989, "male", "35-50", 20, 
  "Germany", 1989, "male", "50-", 1,
  "Germany", 1989, "female", "15-24", 73, 
  "Germany", 1989, "female", "35-50", 2, 
  "Germany", 1989, "female", "50-", 11

)
dataset %>% tail


dataset2 <- dummy_cols(dataset, "age") %>% select(-age)
panel <- pdata.frame(dataset2, index = c("country", "year"))
```

we have multiple observation for one cross-sectional units in one year, because of the age intervals,

how would we transform this dataset to work with it as a panel data and use random or fixed effects?

Using:

```
library(plm)

fixex = plm(suicides_no ~ factor(sex) + factor(age), index = c("country", "year"), data = dataset, model = "within")
```

is not working, how does one transform data so it can be estimated

Comment: I would say that it already has the structure of panel data. You can also run mixed-effects models on it. You can do `lmer(suicides_no ~ sex + age + (1|country), data = dataset)`. Or it is not what you are looking for?

Comment: I would like to use random or fixed models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `plm()` function needs an unique combination of ID and time, indicated by the error message `duplicate couples (id-time)`. When you run:

```
library(dplyr)

dataset %>%
 count(country, year)
```

then you can see, that there are six observations for every country and year combination:

```
  country  year     n
  <chr>   <dbl> <int>
1 Albania  1987     6
2 Albania  1988     6
3 Albania  1989     6
4 Germany  1987     6
5 Germany  1988     6
6 Germany  1989     6
```

To avoid this, you need to create unique IDs. I assume that they can be created based on country, age and gender. Then, you can do:

```
library(broom)

dataset %>%
 mutate(ID = group_indices(., !!!select(., -suicides_no, -year))) %>%
 mutate_at(vars(sex, age), as.factor) %>%
 do(tidy(plm(suicides_no ~ sex + age, 
             index = c("year", "ID"), 
             model = "within",
             data = .)))

  term     estimate std.error statistic p.value
  <chr>       <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>   <dbl>
1 sexmale      5.17      7.82     0.661   0.514
2 age35-50   -15.5       9.57    -1.62    0.116
3 age50-     -10.1       9.57    -1.05    0.301
```